# I want a human (turtle) to walk to a weed (turtle) and then show in console that the human reached the weed and then do nothing

Tags: netlogo

I want a human to walk to a weed and then show in console that it reached the weed and then stop. Whenever I initiate the model a human walks to a weed and shows that it reached the weed but then walks to another weed and does it again, and again... and again.

this is the code (the humans are supposed get 1 food from a weed)

```
to action_human
   if food < 1 [
      ask one-of humans [ 
         let temp-weed one-of weeds
         face temp-weed
         while [distance temp-weed > 1] [
             ifelse distance temp-weed < 1 [ move-to temp-weed ] [ fd 1]
         ] 
         show "weed reached" 
         set food food + 1
      ]
   ]
end
```

Comment: @easleyfixed turtles are one of the four base agent-types used in Netlogo (together with patches, links, and observer). Yolom is using 2 turtle-type agents which they named human and weed

Comment: I see, ty that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Something else in your code must be wrong. I used your exact same code and it behaves as expected described. I attached a full code example.

```
breed [humans human]
breed [weeds weed]

humans-own [food]

to setup
  ca
  create-humans 1 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set food 0
  ]
  create-weeds 1 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask humans [action_human]
  tick
end



to action_human
 if food < 1 [
    ask one-of humans [
     let temp-weed one-of weeds
     face temp-weed
     while [distance temp-weed > 1] 
     [
        ifelse distance temp-weed < 1 
        [
          move-to temp-weed] [
          fd 1
        ]
     ]
     show "weed reached" set food food + 1
    ]
  ]
end
```